# Appending to async loaded content using promise()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `ul` that gets loaded asynchronously. I'd like to append a `button` to the `ul` when it is placed on the DOM.

I'm trying to achieve this using the following:

```
var ul = $(".free-sbs .h.sbs-bot");
ul.promise().done(function() {
    console.log("ul is done");
    ul.append("<button>My Button</button>");
});
```

The console will notify me that "ul is done", however, the button is not being added to the DOM.

However, if I enter `$(".free-sbs .h.sbs-bot").append("<button>My Button</button>");` into the console after the content is loaded, the button will be added properly.

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/tym1n02u/ Is the jQuery selector you're using for `ul` correct?

Comment: Do you really want to add a button to an unordered list, or did you mean ul.after("...")?